# getJSON response handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, get, getjson

This is my Javascript code to handle the response of a getJSON:

```
$.getJSON(url, {
            userID:userID,
            unique:unique
        }, function(response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
           if(response.connection_status == true) {
               alert(response.connected_friends[0].id);
           }
        });
```

The first alert does fire and gives me this:

```
{ "connection_status":true,
  "hasResults":true,
  "connected_friends":{
    "id":"1055",
    "name":"My Name"
  }
}
```

Why is my 2nd alert not showing?

what am I missing here?

Comment: do `response.connected_friends["id"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do

`response.connected_friends["id"]`

or

`response.connected_friends.id`

as it is an **object** not an **Array**

Comment: why then does response.connected_friends work? isn't this an object? and why no "undefined" alert?

Comment: Please try this. It will throw console error. Please check your browser console.

Comment: i'm sorry you are right, i now see that i didn't add an array to my connection_friends array, but i changed connected_friends to this array

Answer (score 1):

You may expect `array` but the API may also return an `object`, so you have to handle both cases.

```
if(response.connected_friends instanceof Array && response.connected_friends.length) {
   alert(response.connected_friends[0].id);
else {
   alert(response.connected_friends.id);
}
```

Comment: in this case correct, but seen the answer of @parth i know what i have done wrong and now i will always have an array returned. thx though!

Comment: `connected_friends ` is pluralized, so I expected that it can return an `Array`.